Understanding PetitParser2 behavior
I'm struggling with a small parser using PetitParser2. Here is a fragment of some of the rules I'm defining but their behaviour is not as I could expect:
andKeyword := 'and' asPParser trim, #letter asPParser not.
notKeyword := 'not' asPParser trim, #letter asPParser not.
keyword := andKeyword / notKeyword.
nonKeywordIdentifier := keyword not, #letter asPParser, #word asPParser star.
word := nonKeywordIdentifier, #blank asPParser star.
words := word star.

The behaviour of the "nonKeywordIdentifier" is the expected:
identifier end parse: 'hello'. "It parses successfully" 
identifier end parse: 'and'. "It fails as 'and' is a keyword"

However the "words" rule's behavior is the following:
words end parse: 'hello Pharo'. "It parses successfully" 
words end parse: 'hello and bye'. "It parses, when I would expect it fails because 'and' is a keyword"

I don't understand why the "words" rule works this way, but I'm starting with PetitParser. Any suggestions?
PS: Sorry for the cross-posting in the Pharo users mailing list.
Thank  you.


words end parse: 'hello and bye'. "It parses, when I would expect it
fails because 'and' is a keyword"

nonKeywordIdentifier := keyword not, #letter asPParser, #word asPParser star.
word := nonKeywordIdentifier, #blank asPParser star.
words := word star.

It parses because you have created a loop. word calling nonKeywordIdentifier and the other way around.  Even thou you have only #letter asPParser, but that will be matched #word asPParser star times (notice the star at the end).
